# When should you wrap a string of HTML in a single element when inserting into DOM via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom, insert

I came across this [article](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx#tip7), which mentions wrapping everything in a single element when inserting into the DOM. He found it has significant performance gains.

My question is, at what point should I be doing this? Should I do it with all HTML insertions, small and large alike, or just large?

Comment: You typically would do that when building large lists or data tables for instance. The gain will not be very significant for a few elements insertion. This article speaks about this but more detailed: [43,439 reasons to use append() correctly](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly).

Comment: That article is four years old, which given the progress of modern browsers means that it's pretty much nonsense now.

Comment: I have read a few articles that say that, although I think they are still valid, even with performance gains we have received within the last 4 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an element to a DOM is costlier than appending DOM to a string variable. So, you should always do it.

Comment: That's not what the article was saying.  The article claimed adding `<ul>..lots of LI tags</ul>` was faster than adding just `..lots of LI tags` - I'd say this was probably just an artifact of the HTML parser on whatever browser the author happened to be using, and may or may not be relevant today.

Comment: @MikeChristensen, correct, so what would be a reasonable amount of text to justify putting tags around it all before calling your .html() or .append(), etc?

Comment: @NickGeorge - I wouldn't worry about it until you're talking about thousands of DOM elements.  And at that point, I'd do some quick tests on the major browsers to see if there's even a difference anymore.